# Self-extracting program with C#

Tags: c#, dotnetzip, self-extracting

when you create a zip/rar file with Winrar, it gives you the chance to create an exe from the zip you just created. Is it possible to do that from C# code???

I'm suspecting the DotNetZip Library can do the work because of these lines at their page:

**Does this library make self-extracting zip files?**
Yes. It can make self-extracting zip files or standard zip files. The self-extracting archives can either be Windows (GUI) apps or command-line applications. The self-extractors require .NET 2.0 on the computer doing the extraction.

Does anybody has used this library that can tell me if it is correct that it supports creating SFX files???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason that makes you doubt the official statement? Did you try something that didn't work?

Comment: Usually when the documentation says 'we can do x' there is a strong possibility it can do x.

Comment: hi, yes there is that quote stating "The self-extracting archives can either be Windows (GUI) apps or command-line applications"... what does it mean??? I don't want GUI neither I want consoles... I mean, I'm not installing anything in the machines that will be executing the SFX file... could you please explain that quote if you have used the library??? Thanks

Comment: It means the library can create an SFX with a graphical interface (with windows, dialogs, textboxes, buttons, and stuff), or an SFX that runs on the command-line. If you don't want neither a graphical nor a command-line interface, what kind of SFX file do you want?

Comment: mmmm... let me see if I understand... Once the user double-click the exe, there will be a window that will start talking to the user??? Like "click next to do this" or "select the place where you that"??? right??? ok, I can live with that, even though I would prefer to avoid dialogs at all, is it possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anybody has used this library that can tell me if it is correct that it supports creating SFX files???

yes, you can make SFX files using DotNetZip.